# .htaccess RewriteRule not working as i needed for my yii2 advance framework

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created this .htaccess rule to show the frontend and backend part:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^backend(/.*)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* /frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php
```

Rule for **backend** part (2nd rule) follow url as i needed like this https://example.com/backend/web/site/login but doesn't load backend login page and only show frontend homepage. i want to show backend login page when user use backend as https://example.com/backend. but, this does not working.

When i am change rule like below, then rule show the backend login page as i needed. but i want to show backend login page only when user type backend in url:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /backend/web/$1 [L]
```

This is working on local side but not working on my 1&1 IONOS dedicated server side.

Please, help me to load my backend login page as i needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

=> .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(uploadImages)
  RewriteRule ^uploadImages/(.*)$ uploadImages/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^backend(.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

=> backend/config/main.php

```
'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/backend', //point to your folder directly 
        ],
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // hide ?r=site%2Fsignup
            'showScriptName' => false, //hide frontend/web/index.php from URL            
            'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<alias:index|>' => 'site/<alias>',
                '<alias:login|logout>' => 'site/<alias>', 
            ], 
        ],
```

Comment: according to your backend/config/main.php it does not redirect to my login page from site controller, still same issue.

Comment: can u share us
 'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/backend', //point to your folder directly 
        ], code of backend/controllers/siteController too and what actually u want to enter in url and what should load?

Comment: my 'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
           'baseUrl' => '/backend',
        ], and 'urlManager' => [
           'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
        ], and i have action index and login in my site controller. when i type backend  shows frontend same page instead of backend login, other details available in question.

Comment: and the same .htaccess you are using which I suggested above.
just for a confirmation, if you are working in local then you must have to use baseurl as projectfoldername/backend. then url should be localhost/projectfoldername/backend.

Comment: i am using htaccess that i have mentioned in my question, and my project directory path on server is /projectName/backend

Comment: @HarshilDholakiya, kindly use .htaccess which I have mentioned in my previous post. Above code is working on my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190542/discussion-between-rups-and-harshil-dholakiya).